# Firefox 32: Download fails; cannot read from source

Tags: firefox, download, file-download

I'm running Firefox 32, and am currently unable to download files. This is the error message I get, for every single download:

> C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\Ch+rOsoW.pdf.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

I've checked everything from **[here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Unable_to_save_or_download_files)**, and have even done a re-install of Firefox, which leads me to believe it's a bug. However, I think that posting here first might lead me to a solution.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: What's your operating system? I can't reproduce the issue using Windows 7 SP1. Did you try using a different user account, [starting Firefox in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode), or [creating a new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager)?

Comment: I had a problem accessing a file on my banking site with FF32.0. I was able to access it with IE, so you may be right about a bug. As FF32.0 is new I´d decided to wait a while before digging deeper as it may be an add-on clash.

Comment: @and31415 - I'm running Windows 8 Pro X64. I did try a new profile, but I didn't try safe mode... Will give that a shot tomorrow (it's my office PC).

Comment: It definitely seems to be related to Firefox. When I switched to Chome it worked fine. This is on OS X as well so it's not Windows specific.